# What is the native word for describing an expression or gesture

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

1. What will be the perfect word for expressing huff, pride or sulking like when children angry with their parents and sit in the corner and don't want to talk with them . What word generally a native use for expressing this facial expression ?
2. What is the perfect word or slang for expressing childish attitude when it is seen in adult person, generally a native use ?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I'm not sure what you mean by "native." Do you mean the natural look of the petulant child? Or the word a native English speaker would use?

Comment: I think "petulant" is the perfect word. "In a snit" would be a slang expression that could be generally used. "Knickers in a twist" (B.E.) or "Panties in a wad" (A.E.) could be used as a borderline rude slang expression.

Comment: There are many variants on _knickers in a twist_ in AE. It's a subject that lends itself to slang, like vomiting.

Comment: @rajah9 I don't think I've usually heard the knickers/panties phrases used to describe children. Perhaps because we don't expect as much decorum, so it seems inappropriate to use such rude phrases to describe them. A child throwing a tantrum is considered relatively normal.

Comment: @Barmar, In part 2 of their question, the OP asked about "a childish attitude when it is seen in (an) adult person." While it may seem inappropriate for a child, I have heard adults warn other adults to not get their knickers in a twist, since the lack of decorum is not considered normal.

Answer (score 1):

1. The facial expression is a **pout**, and the verb for displaying this expression is **to pout**.

Merriam-Webster:

> 1a: to show displeasure by thrusting out the lips or wearing a sullen expression
>
> *a pouting child*
>
> *Sure, you have sports figures misbehaving today. John McEnroe pouts and snarls and curses at tennis judges twice his age, on television …*
>
> *— Roy Blount Jr.*

2. The person might be *sulking, in a snit*... you may be able to find more options by putting "sulk" in a thesaurus.